# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed')

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

When I try to create the last table `gatt_descriptors` I get

> `ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed')`

```
    gatt_profiles (primary key 'version')

CREATE TABLE gatt_profiles(
    version INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    profile_name VARCHAR(25), 
    value VARCHAR(25));

gatt_services (primary key 'service_name')

CREATE TABLE gatt_services(
    service_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    uuid VARCHAR(36),
    id VARCHAR(36),
    declaration_type VARCHAR(10),
    advertise BIT,
    version INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT ver_val FOREIGN KEY (version) REFERENCES gatt_profiles(version) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT pk_verser PRIMARY KEY (service_name, version));

gatt_characteristics (primary key 'char_name')

CREATE TABLE gatt_characteristics(
    char_name VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    uuid VARCHAR(36),
    id VARCHAR(36),
    val_const BIT,
    init_val VARCHAR(25),
    var_length BIT,
    val_length INT,
    read_val VARCHAR(7),
    write_val VARCHAR(7),
    write_wo_response VARCHAR(7),
    reliable_write VARCHAR(7),
    notify VARCHAR(7),
    indicate VARCHAR(7),
    version INT NOT NULL, 
    service_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (version) REFERENCES gatt_profiles (version) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (service_name) REFERENCES gatt_services (service_name) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE);

gatt_descriptors (primary key 'descriptor_name')

CREATE TABLE gatt_descriptors(
    descriptor_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    uuid VARCHAR(36),
    id VARCHAR(36),
    val_const BIT,
    init_val VARCHAR(25),
    var_length BIT,
    val_length INT,
    read_val VARCHAR(7),
    write_val VARCHAR(7),
    version INT NOT NULL, 
    service_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    char_name VARCHAR(25), 
    FOREIGN KEY (char_name, service_name, version) REFERENCES gatt_characteristics (char_name, service_name, version) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT pk_verserchardescr PRIMARY KEY (descriptor_name, char_name, service_name, version));
```

Answer (score 0):

`gatt_characteristics` has a primary key consisting of the single column `char_name`.

The foreign key in `gatt_descriptors` is three columns, the first of which is `char_name`.

When you define a foreign key, it should have exactly the same columns as the primary key of the table it references.